# iPhone 5 resolution and MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, iphone-5

Today, I have received this email from Apple Developer Support:

> If you are updating your app for iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th
>   generation), you must provide additional screenshots to support the
>   new screen dimensions for the App Store.  The new screenshot
>   dimensions are:
>
> - 640 x 1136 (portrait)
> - 640 x 1096 (portrait)
> - 1136 x 640 (landscape)
> - 1136 x 600 (landscape)

But there is no version of MonoDevelop (no alpha or beta release) where this resolution (in iPhone Application Option) is supported. What could I do in this case to submit my application with an icon compliant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MonoDevelop.
The icons of the app still have to be low res for iPhone 3 and "Retina" resolution for iPhone 4(S) and iPad 3.
This mail is about the screenshots that are shown in the App Store.
You can take screenshots of your app using the Xcode Organizer. Logging in to [itunesconnect.apple.com](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) allows you to upload these screenshots for your (submitted) app.